# Can I use LIMIT function in SQL line where it's not SELECT statement, but is UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, limit

Can I use LIMIT function in SQL line where it's not SELECT statement, but is UPDATE?
For example:
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET esh='$esh' LIMIT 2");

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES you can ;)

[UPDATE-Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)